# Optional dependency how JVM works

Tags: java, maven, jvm

It is possible to declare maven dependency as `optional` (https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html), which would mean the dependency is required for the project to build, but not propagated further.

The question is how it works JVM wise, when another project refers the project built with the optional dependency, and this another project doesn't provide this optional dependency.

I.e. why JVM doesn't crash? Or is it due that the class is loaded into the memory only on the first use, and this is why it makes possible to ship the code which compiled when the required dependencies were present, but they are not necessary required to be on the target platform, unless those classes from the project are used?

Is it correct understanding of how and why it works? Are there exceptions from this?

Answer (score 0):

If you use a jar and you don't also add (all) its optional dependencies to your project, this *can* lead to class not being found by the JVM (which essentially kills your program). It depends on whether this class is actually used at runtime.

I can declare a dependency to jar and only use a tiny bit of it, so I might not run into problems. Maybe the jar works with three kinds of databases but I only use one of them, so I leave out the other dependencies.

In general, leaving out dependencies is always a bit of a gamble and sufficient tests should be run to verify that all necessary classes are present.